# String format EngishLocale

Tags: java

Почему если в `String.formant()` передать `Locale.ENGLISH`, дробные числа выдает с точкой, а с другой локалью выдает с запятой?

```java
String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.5f", 62.23);
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял из текста вопроса.

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev изменил

Comment: Ну, потому что традиционно в разных языках принято по-разному форматировать дробные числа.

Comment: А зачем Вы передаете `Locale.ENGLISH`? Просто обычно локаль указывают как раз для того чтобы была точка.

Comment: @default-locale ложе чтобы была точка. просто не понятно было почему так происходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исторически сложилось, что в разных странах используются разные символы для разделения дробной и целой части числа и в качестве разделителей групп разрядов (точно так же, как в разных странах используется разный формат даты). Подробнее о разделителях можно прочесть [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C).

Об использоании локалей в Java имеется статья на сайте Oracle, где в таблице 1 показаны примеры чисел с применением разных локалей: http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/locale-140624.html

Сооответственно, вы можете использовать конкретную локаль для вывода чисел в том формате, в каком нужно вам, либо не передавать локаль и будут использованы текущие настройки операционной системы.